Require the heading date in which column found the first data/value in a specific row
enter image description here






Day Wise Production







Buyer
PO
Start Date
9-Nov
10-Nov
11-Nov
12-Nov
14-Nov


CHS
100
9-Nov-24
3
5
5




KHG
101
11-Nov-24


4
2



Ikea
102
10-Nov-24

4
5
6



Simba
103
9-Nov-24
4
1






I need the attached chart's production start date using an excel formula.
Please help in this regard.
I am trying but failed, I expect solution.
I will be grateful if anyone help me to find out the exact formula.
Thanks in advance.

Enter in C3 and fill-down:
=MINIFS($D$2:$I$2,D3:I3,"<>")

